# Using parent's property and will as evidence of assets

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

Here are the questions regarding showing evidence of asset/property which is parent's name:

1. In my visa application, Can I provide evidence of assets which are in the name of my parents?

If the answer of (1) question is a NO. Then here is next question:

2. In the will of my parents, they have mentioned about me inheriting the property with my brother. In such a case, can I attach the documents of property and the will to show evidence of assets? If Yes,
   Then do I need to present any other certificate from parents for using their will my visa application OR it's not needed?

Comment: I suggest reviewing the classic [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab). Although not directly relevant, it will help you understand how the UK views finances for purposes of issuing visas.

Comment: If you need to consider such approach, you should also honestly ask yourself whether that trip is financially viable. Plan for a contingency or two, as well. Generally speaking, if you're an adult, then assets of people other than your spouse, no matter their relationship to you, are not considered - this is not UK specific but simply a prudent view of things on the part of immigration regulations anywhere.

Comment: In some countries, inheritance by children is mandatory and cannot be overturned by a will (but I have no idea if that applies in India). Even so, if the only way you can spend money during your trip is by getting your parents killed so you get your inheritance, that story is not going to make the visa application department happy!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 42):

Until they die and your parents' wills are probated or settled (I don't know the legal word of art for India), your parents' property is not yours.

Their wills demonstrate that your parents believe that they own the property. Their wills do not provide any evidence that you yourself own this property.

Because wills can be changed, your interest in their property is only an expectancy, and their property cannot be counted as your asset.

Comment: Also immigration officials are looking for evidence that assets are "available to you". Even if the will wasn't changed, the assets aren't available to you now.

Answer (score 20):

The UK wants to know if you are a *genuine* tourist or business traveler, and not trying to overstay and immigrate. They cannot know what you plan to do, so they look at your circumstances.

They want to know who pays for your trip, and also what your finances look like. This is **not** about simply having a fixed amount of money in the bank account. It is about stable, legal **income** exceeding your reasonable **expenses**. Having such income shows a settled, responsible lifestyle and an incentive to return home to that job.

So you will have to explain your finances, and if you cannot afford the trip without borrowing against a future inheritance, things don't look good.

Comment: at least having parents with money at home means *ties to the home country*. Though, if one were to count their parent's money as already inherited, I'd question the strength of these ties..

Comment: @Chieron Not necessarily. Children sometimes walk out on their parents, and parents sometimes disown their children. Both of those are motivations for a child wanting to move *permanently* (but not necessarily legally) to a new environment, independent of the parents' financial situation.

Comment: @Chieron having real estate in your home country or income that's tied to you being there (i.e. job or business) means ties to home country. On the other hand, having none of these but large financial assets (i.e. a pile of cash or rich parents) means you're free to emigrate, the exact opposite of having ties to home country.

Comment: @alephzero Nevermind even needing a schism - young people leave home to find their fortunes all over, even if they still have good relationships with their parents.